# How to create the foreign key in the parent table and assign it to the child table using entity framework in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm developing a website using asp.net mvc with entity framework. I have an existing database and the relationship is shown below.

Parent table:

```
public class Accounts
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public int AddressId { get; set; }

    public virtual Addresses Address { get; set; }

    //Other properties...
}
```

Child table:

```
 public class Addresses
 {
    [Key, ForeignKey("Account")]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }

    public virtual Accounts Account { get; set; }

    //Other properties...
 }
```

//Create user logic:

```
public void CreateUser(UserModel model)
{
        Addresses newAddress = new Addresses()
        {
            ShippingFirstName = "1",
            ShippingLastName = "1",
            ShippingAddress = "1",
            ShippingAddress2 = "1",
            ShippingCity = "1",
            ShippingState = "1",
            ShippingZip = "1",
            ShippingCountry = "1",
            ShippingPhone = "1",
        };

        Accounts newAccount = new Accounts
        {
            UserFirstName = "a",
            UserLastName = "a",
            UserEmail = model.UserEmail,
            UserPassword = model.UserPassword,
            AddressId = 1,
            UserType = "User",
            Address = newAddress
        };
        context.Accounts.Add(newAccount);
        context.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I create the new user using the CreateUser function, the AddressId(primary key) in the Addresses table is the same as the AccountId(primary key, identity column) in the Accounts table after the data is inserted into the database, which means that entity framework uses the UserId as the foreign key and assigns it to the Addresses table. However, in my database, the foreign key is the AddressId in the Accounts table and points to the AddressId in the Addresses table.

Question:

1. Am I setting up the relationship in the entity class correctly?
2. How can I tell entity framework that it should use the AddressId in Accounts table as the foreign key, and assigns it to the AddressId in the Addresses table after context.Accounts.Add(newAccount) and context.SaveChanges()?
3. How should I generate the foreign key(AddressId) in the Accounts table?

Answer (score 0):

`[ForeignKey("Account")]` makes `AddressId` take `Accounts`'s primary key, which is `UserId`.

Split that:

```
public class Addresses
{
    [Key]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Account")]            // Not necessary
    public int AccountId { get; set; } // Necessary

    public virtual Accounts Account { get; set; }

    // Other properties...
}
```

You should set the primary key in an entity:

```
public void CreateUser(UserModel model)
{
    Addresses newAddress = new Addresses()
    {
        ShippingFirstName = "1",
        ShippingLastName = "1",
        ShippingAddress = "1",
        ShippingAddress2 = "1",
        ShippingCity = "1",
        ShippingState = "1",
        ShippingZip = "1",
        ShippingCountry = "1",
        ShippingPhone = "1",
        AddressId = 1 // Set primary key
    };

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi @aaron, in the Accounts table there's already a foreign key(AddressId) pointing to the primary key in the Addresses table. Is it possible to do it without creating a new property(AccountId) in the Addresses table? I set the on delete cascade on the Accounts table. If the account is removed, the associated address is removed as well.

Comment: If you want the navigation property `Account` in `Addresses`, you need a separate `AccountId`. Alternatively, you can have the inverse property `ICollection<Accounts>` which doesn't require a foreign key.

Comment: After I remove the Account navigation property in the Addresses table and set the [ForeignKey("Address")] on the AddressId in the Accounts table, entity framework won't automatically assign the AddressId from the Accounts table to the AddressId in the Addresses table. What's going on? It gives me an exception and says that the AddressId in the Addresses table cannot be null.

Comment: This is what I want to do. If I set the AddressId in the Accounts table to 100, I want the AddressId(primary key) in Addresses is set to 100 automatically when I save the account object.

Comment: Did you read my answer? **You should set the primary key in an entity**.

Comment: I thought the AddressId in the Addresses can be created like the code I show in this post. I have one more question, why does the AddressId in the Addresses table will be created with the UserId in the Accounts table after I add it to the account collection and call the db.save() method?

Comment: I overlooked a point. If you want "If the account is removed, the associated address is removed as well." then the foreign key `AccountId` must be in `Addresses`, not the other way around.

Comment: What if I already set the on delete cascade in the database, do I still need to add the AccountId in the Addresses table?

Comment: `on delete cascade` can only be on a foreign key. What you have set may be the other way around: If the address is removed, the associated account is removed as well.

Comment: In my situation, I think it only makes sense when the account is removed, the associated address is removed too.

Comment: So the foreign key `AccountId` must be in `Addresses`. That's how it works and it's what I've been trying to tell you from the start.

Comment: Thanks for asking. It works but you didn't answer my question.

Comment: What do you mean I didn't answer your question?

Comment: @IYU What do you mean I didn't answer your question?